# Same docker container working differently on different machines

Tags: python, docker

I created a docker container of a Python program and I need to run it on a virtual machine.
I prepared a Dockerfile to create the container, where I launch the main script by using:

```
CMD python3 /home/project_name_folder/script_00.py
```

built it as usual:

```
docker build -t registry_address/image_name -f folder_name/Dockerfile_01 .
```

and pushed the image to a registry. Then, I pulled and ran the image on the VM by:

```
docker run -p 5555:8050 registry_address/image_name
```

The problem is that, on the VM, I'm getting an error which never occurs when I run a container generated from the same image on my PC.

The error looks something like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/project_name_folder/script_02.py", line 188, in <module>
    infile = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'temp/3004601723038773'
```

So, script_00.py is executed, creates the file temp/3004601723038773, and calls another script_02 passing the file name as an argument. However, the container on the VM seems to be unable to find the corresponding file.
What surprises me is that this is never happening when running the container on my local computer, so I assume it's not due to the code itself. Can it be related to the docker version, or something similar?

P.S. sorry if the terminology I'm using is not correct, I'm a beginner when it comes to Docker!

Comment: Looks like you're using relative paths which means that the script is looking for 'temp/3004601723038773' in the current working directory (CWD.) The CWD depends on how you're running the script.

Comment: That exception on its own isn't enough to understand what's going on.  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve], including both the relevant application code and how you're launching the container?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't write it correctly, the path is actually absolute. I run the script by simply using 'CMD python3 /home/project_name_folder/script_00.py' in the Dockerfile